# Magento 2 Can't change theme after move to new server

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.3.3, change

I have moved my Magento 2.3.3 to a new server. Every seems work fine, But I can't change theme.

Configure:
CONTENT > Elements > Design > Configuration > Select Edit > Default Theme > Applied Theme > select Magento Luma > Save Configuration
But it show a bug

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at mydomain.com Port 80
```

Thank you for your advanced!

Comment: Have you check file and folder permission? Is this as per magento 2 guide line?

Comment: Thank you! I did try some command line: find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
I have try setup system configure but it work fine.

Comment: Can you please check logs? Is anything helpful information available in log files?

Comment: Do you mean log file of server or Magento?

Comment: Magento log files. debug.log, exception.log, system.log

Comment: I have checked it, but it have no bug in there.

Comment: Thank you. I have asked our server and they have fixed it.